# Force an specific link (a tag) to have the default style for links

Tags: html, css

Whenever I add a link on my blog, they automatically appear with the style I gave them in CSS long time ago (that is in bold, pink, only underlined when when hovering over, and a lighter pink if it has been read)

However, I want to add a link on a blog post, and I want that link to have the default style of links (that is, blue, underlined, purple when read...)

I wonder if there's an attribute that cancels other orders.

Or if there's an attribute that means "do what you'd do by defaul" or something like that

Thanks so much!

Comment: It would help if you provided the CSS. It's likely you're having a CSS specificity issue, which is causing your CSS overrides to not work properly.

Comment: Not really...there are some that can be reset but you'd probably need to actually override others by using a separate class (or distinct selector).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a separate class for the one that you want and set the style.